# Auto Submit UpdatePanel and show UpdateProgress area

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I want to auto submit my form and show the update progress area once it is submitted. I have tired adding 2 functions to the page:

```
window.onload=function(){
     __doPostBack('UpdatePanelId','');
}
```

and....

```
window.onload=function(){
     var btn = document.getElementById('buttonID');
     btn.click();
}
```

The page gets posted back to, but the progress area is not showing up. Any thoughts how I can handle this?

Comment: wouldn't the upload control cause full page postback? from what i understand UpdateProgress won't show up on FULL POSTBACK.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your further comments:

you have an `UpdatePanel` and `SomeUploadControl` outside of that panel. You want to show `UpdateProgress` when you cause a FULL POSTBACK from `SomeUploadControl`.

If the above assumptions are correct - I'm afraid you can't do what you want. The whole idea behind the `UpdateProgress` is to work on PARTIAL POSTBACKS.

I'm pretty sure the above is correct, but I might be mistaken.

---

Edited in light of your comment :)

try:

```
window.onload=function(){
     __doPostBack('buttonID','');
}
```

if this doesn't work - give more details on the problem you're trying to solve (why are you trying to cause the postback via javascript), and there might be a better way altogether.

Comment: I am using this control. I assumed my title gave that away. When the page is auto submitted, the UpdateProgress control is not showing up.

Comment: Well, I have an upload page and I am using a 3rd party upload control to handle the file upload. The control cannot be put into and updatepanel. The user will upload a list of e-mail addresses in CSV format. After the upload the file gets processed, but it can take a few minutes. My site makes use of the updateprogress control and it is pretty standard throughout the site. So, we would liek to keep it the same.

Comment: I forogot to add...After the upload is doen the site is redirected to a page to process the file. I have it auto submitting so the user doens't need to have any interaction.

Comment: wouldn't the upload control cause full page postback? from what i understand UpdateProgress won't show up on FULL POSTBACK.

Comment: That is why there is not updatepanel on the file upload page. I stated that. The updatepanel and updateprogress are on the file process page. Does that make sense?

Comment: The file upload page uplaods the file then redirects to the process file page. When the process file page loads the script in my questions is executed.

Comment: Sorry, my typing is so poor today. I am trying to do to many things at once ;)

Comment: I think you are correct. Never thought about that. It's strange, though that when I try the second method in my question it doesn't work. Hmmmm.....

Comment: This wasn't working because of the hierarchy naming convention: 'buttonID' was probably something like '$ctl1$ctl2$buttonID' or something. (I'm talking about the argument to __doPostBack)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!!

Origianlly, I had my script running inside the ScriptManager client script block. I moved it outside of the script manager and added a timeout to the script. Here is what it looks like:

```
            Dim script As String = "window.onload = function(){" & vbCrLf
            script += "setTimeout('submitPage()',2000);}" & vbCrLf
            script += "function submitPage(){" & vbCrLf
            script += " var btn = document.getElementById('" & Me.btnProcess.ClientID & "');" & vbCrLf
            script += "btn.click();}" & vbCrLf    
                            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page.GetType, "autosubmit", script, True)
```

Comment: I didn't try this, but I guess i could have added the code to the Sys.Application.add_load